# Change class name in ngFor based on Viewport - expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: css, angular, typescript, viewport, ng-class

On the left, there's a navigation list with titles of categories, and on the right, I have the categories listed. The titles in the list could get "highlighted" based on the category shown on the right.
1- The user may click on a category title from the list to scroll to it, and now that clicked title would get "highlighted".
2- The Title could get "highlighted" if the user scrolls into its corresponding category section.
"Highlighting" category titles is simply done by assigning `faq__category-m-heading w--current` to its class. Non-highlighted titles have the `faq__category-m-heading` class.

**HTML**

```
//Left
<div class="faq__category-menu">

        <a *ngFor="let category of DISPLAYED_CATEGORIES" (click)="scrollToElement(category.FAQ_CATEGORY_ID)"
           [ngClass]="getClass(category.FAQ_CATEGORY_ID)">{{category.FAQ_CATEGORY_TITLE}}</a>

</div>

//Right
<div *ngFor="let category of DISPLAYED_CATEGORIES" id="{{category.FAQ_CATEGORY_ID}}"
        class="faq__category-wrapper food">
        <h2 class="faq__category-heading">{{category.FAQ_CATEGORY_TITLE}}</h2>
//nonn relevant code section here
</div>
```

**TypeScript**

```
 scrollToElement($elementId): void {
    this.currentID = $elementId;  //I was trying another method here
    let el = document.getElementById($elementId);
    el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "nearest" });
  } 

isInViewport(elem) {
    var bounding = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
      bounding.top >= 0 &&
      bounding.left >= 0 &&
      bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
      bounding.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
  };

getClass(id) {
    let el = document.getElementById(id);
    if (el == undefined || el == null)
      return 'faq__category-m-heading';
    else {
      if (this.isInViewport(el)) {
        return 'faq__category-m-heading w--current';
      }
      else
        return 'faq__category-m-heading';
    }
}
```

**scrollToElement function scrolls to the category depending on the id passed by the parameter (thus now it's in the viewport).
**isInViewport function returns true if category is currently in viewport (first time I use this I don't know if it could be enhanced).
**getClass dynamically changes classes based on if they're in the viewport or not.

This code "apparently" works but throws expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError.
Side question: the function getClass() gets called from each object around 3 times... why is this happening?

Thank you for any help in advance, I tried searching for similar cases but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the `expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error because the DOM has been updated outside of an Angular lifecycle hook while in development mode.

Specifically, when the click handler is called, this tells Angular to check the view for changes. The view checks if there are any differences once the click handler returns. However, in your click handler you call the `scrollIntoView` function which is essentially asynchronous because you don't know exactly when the element will be scrolled into view. The `getClass` is called on every change detection cycle. However, your `getClass()` method relies on the `scrollIntoView` asynchronous method to hightlight whichever DOM is in view.

Angular tries to be smart in development mode and will force a change detection after any nominal change detection occurs (i.e., a click event) to check if there are any divergences in the DOM and what Angular holds in it's local state. This is to prevent undefined behavior from happening in production. Production won't do this extra change detection so your program may not work in prod.

**TL, DR. You are seeing an `expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` because you are relying on asynchronous code to update the DOM.**

**Solutions:**

1. Wrap the asynchronous code in an `NgZone.run()`. This will trigger an update once the async code finishes.

```
scrollToElement($elementId): void {
   this.currentID = $elementId;  //I was trying another method here
   let el = document.getElementById($elementId);
   this.ngZone.run(() =>
       el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "nearest" });
   );
```

2. Don't rely on async code to update the DOM. You should be able to do this synchronously by setting the elementId locally upon click.

```
// template.html
<a *ngFor="let category of DISPLAYED_CATEGORIES
    (click)="scrollToElement(category.FAQ_CATEGORY_ID)"
    [ngClass]="{'active': category.id === currentID}">
        {{category.FAQ_CATEGORY_TITLE}}
</a>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with ngZone.run() could you please elaborate on that and its usage? How would it help and what's the needed code to be written (/where?) (if any extra information is required on my part let me know)

Comment: Hello again, just wanted to not the second solution you provided, apart from the syntax error, it doesn't perform the needed task. See I need to change the class not just when the user clicks on the title but also depending on what category is in the viewport. If category 1 is shown Title 1 is active, if user scrolls to category 3 title 3 should become active by itself. I'm still clueless on the usage of ngZone. Hope you could provide more help on my issue

Comment: I added an ngZone run example. And I didn't realize you needed to highlight the item when the user scrolls. I'd recommend looking into mutation and intersection observers. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API